# Why is the double pound needed in one place but not the others in this macro?

Tags: c++, macros

In this particular bit of code, the author does something clever by using a macro to create incrementor functions for all members of the class COUNTER.

```
class COUNTER
{
    public:
        UINT64 _call;
        UINT64 _call_indirect;
        UINT64 _return;
        UINT64 _syscall;
        UINT64 _branch;
        UINT64 _branch_indirect;

        COUNTER() : _call(0),_call_indirect(0), _return(0), _branch(0), _branch_indirect(0) {}

        UINT64 Total()
        {
             return _call + _call_indirect + _return + _syscall + _branch + _branch_indirect;
        }
};

COUNTER CountSeen;
COUNTER CountTaken;

#define INC(what) VOID inc ## what (INT32 taken) { CountSeen. what ++; if( taken) CountTaken. what ++;}

INC(_call)
INC(_call_indirect)
INC(_branch)
INC(_branch_indirect)
INC(_syscall)
INC(_return)
```

I'm a little confused by the macro, though. Why does the author use the double pound in the function definition part of the macro and not when its being used as the class variable being incremented?

EDIT: I get that the double pound is for concatenation, but my confusion comes from why the double pound is not necessary in the 
    "CountSeen. what ++"
and
    "CountTaken. what ++"
parts.

Comment: Short answer: Double pound sign (`##`) is the preprocessor operator for concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s look at what the first macro (`INC(_call)`) call expands to:

```
VOID inc_call (INT32 taken) { CountSeen. _call ++; if( taken) CountTaken. _call ++;}
```

Reformatting a bit, we get:

```
VOID inc_call (INT32 taken) {
    CountSeen._call++;
    if(taken)
        CountTaken._call++;
}
```

This declares a function, `inc_call`, that increments `CountSeen._call` and maybe also `CountTaken._call`. Since the variables aren’t called `._call` (which is an invalid token, since you can’t start a name with a period), the period should not be glued to the macro argument. Similarly, since `_call++` isn’t a valid token (it’s two tokens; you can’t include plus signs in a name), there shouldn’t be pound signs there.

However, without the first `##`, the result would start `VOID inc _call (INT32 taken)`, which is also invalid C++ because it would have two function names.

Comment: Ahhhh, this makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The double hash `##` is used for concatenation. Thus

```
INC(_call)
```

expands to

```
VOID inc_call (INT32 taken) { CountSeen. _call ++; if( taken) CountTaken. _call ++;}
```

Note that `CountSeen. _call ++;` is equivalent to `CountSeen._call++;`, but that `inc _call` is not equivalent to `inc_call`.

Answer (score 0):

Double pound is just a syntax allowing concatenating two terms in preprocessor syntax.

Consider simple example:

```
#define foo(x) foo_##x

void foo_1();
void foo_2();

...

foo(1); // this will call foo_1
```

Comment: Right, but why isn't it needed in the "CountSeen. what ++" and "CountTaken. what ++" parts?

Comment: @AnthonyCabrera: Because the parser won't read `X.Y` as a single token, but as `X`, `.`, and `Y`.

Comment: Because you do not need to concatenate there. You already have two individual tokens.